# Several types of entities in one postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several types of **resource entities** such as ***resume, vacancy, company, worker***, etc which have some common fields.

And I have some **other entities** such as ***note, discussion, ticket*** which can be bound (not always) to any type of resource.

For now I have tables for each of the resource entities and 
for each of other entities and also tables for common fields between different entities, for example address table.

But in all the bound tables I have columns like ***entity_type*** and ***entity_id*** to reference a resource entity which my note or discussion is bound to.

What are the drawbacks of having just one table 'resource' for all resource entities instead with columns for all fields like:

```
entity_type
resume_field1
resume_field2
...
vacancy_field1
vacancy_field2
...
common_field1
common_field2
...
```

and all other tables for entities bound to some resource will **get rid of the entity_type column** and just have entity_id column to reference a resource.

The pros which I see are **the possibility to set cascade deletion** of all notes and discussions if I delete a resource entity.

I can think of the drawbacks like more RAM consumption, more use of disk space and speed reduction due to holding space for empty fields but I'm not sure how the postgresql stores data and works internally.

Most of the resource fields are string (or text) and boolean. There are less than 100 columns as a whole.

If I set all indexes for 'resource' table, will there be any drawbacks or it's really going to make problems?

Comment: You may want to look into table inheritance in Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-inheritance.html).  It may do what you want.

Comment: It can help with columns naming but it won't help to get rid of entity_type column for all bound to resources entities. The idea is all the tables like note and discussion to have just a resource_id column referencing resources table.